# c# How can I add album art/ image tag to a custom filetype?

Tags: c#, image, tags, mp3, albumart

I am trying to make my own file type which features a thumbnail.

The thumbnail shell handler (CppShellExtThumbnailHandler) seemed to be exactly what I wanted.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppShellExtThumbnailHandler-32399b35

Basically my filetype is an **XML** that I rename so that it has my own custom extension and inside it I store a base64 image which I convert back to an image to be used as a thumbnail in windows explorer. But unfortunately the thumbnail that the *thumbnail shell handler* creates, is recognized only by the **windows explorer**, but not by other image viewer applications such as **Infranview** or **Acdsee** (32 or 64bit versions).

So I am currently trying to see if anyone knows how album art/ image tags work in mp3 files, which seem to be compatible with other image viewers (at least with the old version of Acdsee v3.1) and if this structure could be applied to a custom filetype?
Thank you!